# React material - getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'transition' of undefined when testing popper component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-popper

I am using [react material and the `popper`](https://v3.material-ui.com/api/popper/) component in my project. I am trying to test component that uses `popper` with unit test.

This are the methods in the component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openMenu: false,
    };
  }

  onToggleMenu() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({openMenu: !prevState.openMenu}))
  }

  onCloseMenu() {
    this.setState({openMenu: false})
  }
```

And this is the part of the render where I use popper:

```
         <IconButton
              classes={{root: classes.expandButton}}
              aria-label="menu"
              buttonRef={node => this.anchorEl = node}
              aria-owns={openMenu ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={() => this.onToggleMenu()}
            >
              <ArrowDropDownIcon fontSize="large"/>
            </IconButton>
            <Popper open={openMenu} anchorEl={this.anchorEl} placement="bottom-end" transition disablePortal>
              {({TransitionProps, placement}) => (
                <Grow
                  {...TransitionProps}
                  id="menu-list-grow"
                  style={{transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom'}}
                >
                  <Paper>
                    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => this.onCloseMenu()}>
                      <MenuList disablePadding>
                        <MenuItem onClick={onDeaktiver}>Deaktiver</MenuItem>
                      </MenuList>
                    </ClickAwayListener>
                  </Paper>
                </Grow>
              )}
            </Popper>
```

I have tried to test this like this:

```
it('opens the menu', async () => {
    const header = editor.findByType(EditorHeader);
    expect(header.instance.state.openMenu).toBeFalsy();
    const menuButton = header.findByProps({'aria-label': 'menu'});
    menuButton.props.onClick();
    expect(header.instance.state.openMenu).toBeTruthy();
})
```

But, then I get the error:

> Error: Failed: "Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'transition' of undefined]

How can I mock popper or fix this so that I have this test work?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with MUI Menu component.

It seems there is a known [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17992) with react-transition-group. There are few workarounds posted in the ticket, but most of them didn't work for me, so I've ended up mocking the MUI component.

```js
jest.mock('@material-ui/core', () => {
  const materialUI = jest.requireActual('@material-ui/core');
  return {
    ...materialUI,
    Menu: jest.fn(({ children, open }) => (open ? children : null)),
  };
});
```

Comment: Works for the `Snackbar` component as well. Thanks!